# Django: .annotate gives back unexpected results

Tags: python, django

Currently, I have these two query sets:

```
(
Event.objects.filter(organizer=1)
.values('pk', 'organizer')
.annotate(
    sold_tickets=Count('attendees', filter=Q(attendees__canceled=False))
)
.order_by('organizer')
)


(
Event.objects.filter(organizer=1)
.values('pk', 'organizer')
.annotate(available_tickets=Coalesce(Sum('tickets__quantity'), 0))
.order_by('organizer')
)
```

Results are:

```
<EventQuerySet [{'pk': 6, 'organizer': 1, 'sold_tickets': 1}, {'pk': 1, 'organizer': 1, 'sold_tickets': 529}, {'pk': 5, 'organizer': 1, 'sold_tickets': 1}, {'pk': 4, 'organizer': 1, 'sold_tickets': 2}]>
<EventQuerySet [{'pk': 1, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 1721}, {'pk': 4, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 30}, {'pk': 5, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 10}, {'pk': 6, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 20}]>
```

Now my idea was to combine these. However, I always get unexpected and wrong numbers in my query:

```
(
Event.objects.filter(organizer=1)
.values('pk', 'organizer')
.annotate(
    available_tickets=Coalesce(Sum('tickets__quantity'), 0),
    sold_tickets=Count('attendees', filter=Q(attendees__canceled=False))
)

.order_by('organizer')
)
```

Here the result

```
<EventQuerySet [{'pk': 6, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 20, 'sold_tickets': 2}, {'pk': 1, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 1765746, 'sold_tickets': 2116}, {'pk': 5, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 10, 'sold_tickets': 1}, {'pk': 4, 'organizer': 1, 'available_tickets': 60, 'sold_tickets': 4}]>
```

Is there something about `.annotate` that I don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems I got the same problem before, but I not sure if it is exactly your. Try add `distinct=True` to your `annotate`, which should be:

```
.annotate(
    available_tickets=Coalesce(Sum('tickets__quantity'), 0)
).annotate(
    sold_tickets=Count('attendees', filter=Q(attendees__canceled=False), distinct=True)
)
```

Or you can try add `.distinct()` like this:

```
.annotate(
    available_tickets=Coalesce(Sum('tickets__quantity'), 0),
    sold_tickets=Count('attendees', filter=Q(attendees__canceled=False))
).distinct('available_tickets','sold_tickets')
```

Here is what I found my solution: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Comment: That's interesting, thank you James. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. I guess `available_tickets=Coalesce(Sum(` makes the problems there